# Difference Between Linq to XML and Linq to Objects

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, linq

So I'm trying to figure out the difference between linq to xml and linq to objects.

Linq to Entities has fundamental differences such as you don't have to worry about null references and string searching is always case insensitive. For instance

Linq To Entities will not throw if the content table is null

```
 db.Posts(x => x.Content.Page > 3)
```

While the same Query will throw for linq to objects.

In Linq to XML it is my understanding that you have to load everything into an XML document and you are just calling functions on that document.  Isn't this the same thing as linq to objects since you are accessing those nodes based on the list of nodes in memory.

If not what are the differences between Linq to XML and Linq to objects?

Comment: Where is @JonSkeet when you need him?

Comment: FYI EF is not the reason string  searching is case insensitive, that's completely determined by the setting of the DB you run it on.

Comment: @juharr yeah I know I was just using linq to entities as an example

Comment: Linq-to-XML is closer to Linq-to-objects than EF is because EF is translating your query into SQL where as the others are running them on sequences in memory.  Really all Linq-to-XML adds is a better DOM for doing Linq on.

Comment: LINQ to XML and LINQ to Objects are flavors of LINQ.  LINQ to XML has extension methods specific to navigating/working with XML via the `XDocument` object.

Comment: @tim oh so there are explicit extension methods for workinng with XML that  I didn't know

Comment: @johnny5 - Yes.  See [Extension Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.extensions(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: That makes sense I thought Descendants etc... were always properties of the XMLDocument